# How to convert Object Detection model to CoreML

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, coreml, coremltools

I have SSD MobilenetV2 model trained using object detection API (tensorflow version 2.8.2). How can I convert it to coreml? Tried to use coremltools  (version 5.2), but failed.

I did the following:

1. Converted checkpoints to saved_model.pb using exporter_main_v2.py
2. Loaded the model using `tf.saved_model.load(model_path)`
3. Run `coremltools.convert(model, source="tensorflow")`

On step 3 I got the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Expected model format: [SavedModel | [concrete_function] | tf.keras.Model | .h5], got <tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject object at 0x7fab1a41cd90>
```

Comment: If I haven't answered your question, please show complete code - for instance you do not show how the "model" variable is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Coremltools is expecting a Keras .h5 model but you are providing a checkpoint.

You will need to instantiate the same class model the checkpoint came from, load the checkpoint, then provide the model to CoreML.